# json array to ul li Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, json

I have a json array and want to convert to ul li but I got error:

```
$data = '[{
  "sym": [{
    "Cough" : [
     {
      "title" : "Cough is",
      "options" : {
        "1" : "Dry",
        "2" : "Producing phlegm or sputum"
      }
    },{
      "title":"Problem is",
         "options" : {
        "3" : "New or recent",
        "4" : "Ongoing or recurrent",
        "5" : "Worsening or progressing"
      }
    }
    ],
    "Ear problems": [
      {
        "title" : "Triggered by",
        "options" : {
          "1" : "Change in air pressure",
          "2" : "Injury or trauma"
        }
      }
    ]
  }]
}]';

$json = json_decode($data, true);
```

What I have tried is:

```
foreach($json[0]['sym'][0] as $js){
    foreach($js as $j){
        echo "<li>". $j['title']."</li>";
    }
}
```

But It just echo "title" but I want to echo nested like this:

```html
<ul>
    <li>Cough
        <ul>
            <li>Cough is
                <ul>
                    <li>Dry</li>
                    <li>Producing phlegm or sputum</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Problem is
                <ul>
                    <li>New or recent</li>
                    <li>Ongoing or recurrent</li>
                    <li>Worsening or progressing</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Ear problems</li>
</ul>
```

Feel free to change structure of json array, I made it handly.

error:

> Array to string conversion in

Comment: So loop over `$j['options']` then as well to create the innermost LI …?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `foreach` with:

```
foreach($json[0]['sym'][0] as $js){
    foreach($js as $j){
        echo "<li>". $j['title'] . "<ul>";
        foreach ($j['options'] as $opt) {
            echo "<li>". $opt."</li>";
        }
        echo "</ul></li>";
    }
}
```

Comment: But this not echo name.

Comment: @tourtravel can you tell me what does the above code print and what you expect it to print. You can edit your question and add as an update below.